# How do I configure ssh proxycommand correctly to run docker exec?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, proxy, docker

I have a host defined in `/etc/hosts` called `web1`.
There is a docker container with the name `store`.

While on my workstation I can ssh into the machine and execute the command to enter the container interactively like this

```
ssh -t -t web1 docker exec -ti store /bin/bash
```

It properly drops me right into the container as root as I had hoped.

However, I really want to define a pseudo host named `store` and set it up in my `~/.ssh/config` file like this using `ProxyCommand` so I can use `ssh store`

```
Host store
ProxyCommand ssh -t -t web1 docker exec -ti store /bin/bash
```

But it fails with the following error:

```
Bad packet length 218958363.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to UNKNOWN: message authentication code incorrect
Killed by signal 1.
```

If I add -v for some debugging, the last two lines just before the block above are

```
debug1: Authenticating to store:22 as 'user1'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

1. I think it is trying `ssh` into the `store` container instead of just executing the command which is throwing that error, is that correct? If not what is the issue?
2. Is there a way to do this using ProxyCommand without trying to ssh into the container but instead just use the docker exec?
3. Is it easy enough to also setup the ssh into the container? We currently aren't doing that as a matter of practice.
4. Is there another option other than an alias for `ssh-store`?

The end goal is to have a virtual host defined that I can just say `ssh store` and have it end up in the `store` container on `web1`.

Edited:

**Solution:**

As Jakuje indicated, using the ProxyCommand with ssh is not going to allow a non-ssh further command. Therefore I am just using an alias and potentially a bash function for this to accomplish it. I've setup both.

Also per Jakuje's recommendation in ~/.ssh/config

```
Host web1
RequestTTY yes
```

in ~/.bash_aliases

```
alias ssh-store="ssh web1 docker exec -ti store /bin/bash"
```

so I can do  `ssh-store` and end up in the container

or in ~/.bashrc

```
function ssh-web1 { ssh web1 docker exec -ti $1 /bin/bash; }
```

so I can do `ssh-web1 store` and also end up in the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it is trying ssh into the store container instead of just executing the command which is throwing that error, is that correct? If not what is the issue?

Yes

> Is there a way to do this using ProxyCommand without trying to ssh into the container but instead just use the docker exec?

No. It does not work this way. `ProxyCommand` expects the other step to be also SSH session and not direct bash prompt.

> Is it easy enough to also setup the ssh into the container? We currently aren't doing that as a matter of practice.

I think this is unnecessary overhead. But it is possible as described in many other questions around here.

At least you can get rid of `-t -t` by specifying `RequestTTY` in your `~/.ssh/config`. But the rest have to be bash alias or function (if you have more host [function](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) is more appropriate).

```
function ssh-docker {
    ssh web1 docker exec -ti $1 /bin/bash
}
```

and then you can call it regardless the container like this:

```
ssh-docker store
```

You just store such function into your `.bashrc` or where you stored your aliases.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I added `RequestTTY yes` to my `web1` entry in my `~/.ssh/config` and I now at least have an alias `ssh-store` using `alias ssh-store="ssh web1 docker exec -ti store /bin/bash"` What is an example of what you mean by using a bash function? What would the function do beyond what the alias is doing and where does the function live?

Comment: added the function example

Comment: Ah, that's great. Thanks for the great tidbit. As a bonus I see that even functions defined like that are available via tab-completion so I can setup multiple functions and aliases like that and tab-complete them. Nice. Thanks.